# Which process is going to be hijacking a tcp port?

Tags: sql-server, windows, tcp

I have a SQL server running on port 1433. Sometimes (maybe always) when someone tries to restart the instance, port 1433 is hijacked by another process. When the Windows server is restarted by the user, SQLservr.exe is able to use port 1433 again. Because this only happens sporadically, user only reported this now. This server is a production server, so I would not like to stop the instance to check with TCPView.

So, is there a way to monitor which process tries to open a specific port (the offending process), but fails because its already open (by SQL server)?

Comment: If you want a tool that can predict what other tools are going to do in the future, you don't have a software problem but a math problem. There's no "processes that want to use a port when it becomes free" list, a port is either in use or free.

Comment: Perhaps ETW for [`AFD_EVENT_CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448763(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Logger from [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552060(v=vs.8) or [API Monitor](http://apimonitor.com/), which record and display function calls and other actions of a program.

API Monitor is much easier to use. First enable Internet and Networking from API Filter. You can monitor suspicious processes and filter results with the port number.

Below screenshot is an example of a python process trying to listen on port 8000 by calling API.

[image: A python process is trying to listen on port 8000]

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer even though apparently my question is off-topic. Although I could also see this from a programming viewpoint, that an application can test the port, and instead of a generic message that the port is already in use (or more annoyingly, silently stop running), that the application might find out which other application is already using the port and report that to the user (or log file).

I will try API Monitor.